# Python Slippy-map Tile Generation

Tags: python, leaflet, scikit-image

I inherited two Python scripts (more like fragments) from a former colleague. The code is supposed to convert a high res image (png) into zoomable tiles ([slippy-map](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Python)) that can be used by [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html) in goographic coordinate space (lat/long).

Not being a Python (or GIS) guy, I'm struggling to get them working properly. I can not determine if the problem is my lack of knowledge or the code...

This first script works as expected, producing five image files of progressively lower resolution, derived from the input image (myImgMaxRez.png). I believe this is referred to as the 'Image Pyramid'. The dimensions of each z[1..5].png are divisible by 256.

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import transform
import skimage

z1 = io.imread("myImgMaxRez.png", as_grey=True)
io.imsave("z1.png",skimage.img_as_uint(z1))

z2 = transform.pyramid_reduce(z1)
io.imsave("z2.png",skimage.img_as_uint(z2))

z3 = transform.pyramid_reduce(z2)
io.imsave("z3.png",skimage.img_as_uint(z3))

z4 = transform.pyramid_reduce(z3)
io.imsave("z4.png",skimage.img_as_uint(z4))

z5 = transform.pyramid_reduce(z4)
io.imsave("z5.png",skimage.img_as_uint(z5))
```

The next script to generate the slippy-map tiles throws a type conversion error (float to int).

```
import math
import os
from skimage import io

def createTiles(xStart, yStart, zoom, theData):
    ncols = theData.shape[1]/256
    nrows = theData.shape[0]/256
    print(nrows, ncols)
    topDir = "%d" % (zoom)
    os.mkdir(topDir)
    for i in range(0, ncols):
        theDir = topDir + "/%d" % (i+xStart)
        print (theDir)
        os.mkdir(theDir)
        for j in range(0, nrows):
            theFile = topDir + "/%d/%d.png" % (i + xStart, j + yStart)
            print (theFile)
            io.imsave(theFile, theData[j*256:(j+1)*256, i*256(i+1)*256])

def num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom):
    n= 2.0 ** zoom
    lon_deg = xtile / n *360.0 -180.0

    lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n )))
    lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
    return (lat_deg, lon_deg)

def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
    lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
    n= 2.0 ** zoom
    xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)
    ytile = int((1.0 - math.log(math.tan(lat_rad) + (1 / math.cos(lat_rad))) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)
    return (xtile, ytile)

# Take center point of interest (MCK). Since z tile is 4x3 go 1 tile up and 2 left
startZoom = 18
centerLoc = deg2num(43.533942709166325, -96.71487003564836, startZoom)
startCol = centerLoc[0]
startRow = centerLoc[1]

# Now get lat/long of upper left tile corner
geoCoord = num2deg(startCol, startRow, startZoom)

loc = deg2num(geoCoord[0], geoCoord[1],18)
# EDIT: reading the .png thanks to JH comment below
z1 = io.imread("z1.png", as_grey=True)
createTiles(loc[0], loc[1], 18, z1)

loc = deg2num(geoCoord[0], geoCoord[1],19)
# EDIT: reading the .png thanks to JH comment below
z2 = io.imread("z2.png", as_grey=True)
createTiles(loc[0], loc[1], 19, z2)

loc = deg2num(geoCoord[0], geoCoord[1],20)
# EDIT: reading the .png thanks to JH comment below
z3 = io.imread("z3.png", as_grey=True)
createTiles(loc[0], loc[1], 20, z3)

loc = deg2num(geoCoord[0], geoCoord[1],21)
# EDIT: reading the .png thanks to JH comment below
z4 = io.imread("z4.png", as_grey=True)
createTiles(loc[0], loc[1], 21, z4)

loc = deg2num(geoCoord[0], geoCoord[1],22)
# EDIT: reading the .png thanks to JH comment below
z5 = io.imread("z5.png", as_grey=True)
createTiles(loc[0], loc[1], 22, z5)
```

CreateTiles() is throwing an error on line `for i in range(0, ncols):` saying `TypeError: float object cannot be interpreted as an integer`... Interestingly, it creates the first sub-directory `18/` before throwing the error. I have confirmed again the dimensions of the z[1..5].png are powers of 2 (or multiples of 256).

Why am i having this this error converting float to integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a Python version issue.. In 2.7, if the result of a divide is xx.0, it's an int.  In Python 3.x, it's a float.  So 512/256 = 2 in Python 2.7 and it's = 2.0 in python 3.x.

By casting the results of the division to an INT, I was able to get it to run.

```
ncols = int(theData.shape[1]/256)
nrows = int(theData.shape[0]/256)
```

Answer (score 1):

`z1` went out of scope when the first script terminated, so it's not available to the second script. You'll need to find a way to pass it in, e.g. just before the call to createTiles() you might do:

```
z1 = io.imread("z1.png", as_grey=True)
```

Those scripts are poorly structured. Keeping `import`s at top level (no indent) makes sense, but it would be good to move the other statements into functions of their own. At a minimum they should be under this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

That way you stand a chance of one script being able to reuse functions from another script, as you can `import` without side effects.

Comment: Thank you for this. The first part of this was very helpful... feels like I'm close to a solution but not there yet. Again, thank you for your help and willingness to look at this...